# Is there an ordering of images for a monotonic function of infinitely many variables?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose I have a function $f:\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \rightarrow [0,1]$ which is monotonically increasing in each variable; that is it satisfies
$$ f(x_n, \{x_m=c_m\}_{m\neq n}) \leq f(x'_n, \{x_m=c_m\}_{m\neq n}) $$
for constants $c_m$, where $x'_n > x_n$. Suppose that $x_n\in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 \}$ for every $x_n$.

Then how can I prove that the images of $f$ are ordered as per the real numbers? That is the image of $x_1x_2x_3\dots $ is greater that or equal to $y_1y_2y_3\dots$ iff the decimal number $0.x_1x_2x_2\dots \geq 0.y_1y_2y_3\dots$

Comment: What do you mean by 'monotonic' on a function of infinitely many variables, other than the condition you suggest? As it stands (without a specific definition of 'monotonic' this statement isn't necessarily true.

Comment: Have redefined: I agree my monotonic statement wasn't helpful. I essentially meant that if we keep all arguments constant except $x_n$, then force the function to be monotonically increasing in $x_n$, for all $x_n$, then does this condition hold? Is that clear or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

The statement as written is still incorrect. Indeed, there are infinitely many counterexamples: let $\mathcal{P}$ be a 'permutation of $\mathbb{N}$' — that is, a 1-1 function from $\mathbb{N}\mapsto\mathbb{N}$ — and define $f(\{x_n\}) = \sum_n 12^{-\mathcal{P}(n)}x_n$. Then clearly $f()$ satisfies your condition, but it will only be a match to the 'natural' order if $\mathcal{P}$ is the identity permutation.

There are also many other counterexamples; for instance, the definition as currently written (even updated to strict monotonicity, i.e. if the $\leq$ is replaced with a $\lt$) doesn't require that the function be one-to-one, so a function like $f(\{x_n\})=1-\sum_{i=0}^\infty 2^{-2^i(1+\sum_{j=2^i}^{2^{i+1}-1}x_j)}$ satisfies it.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed reply -- you're obviously correct! Suppose I update the conditions on the function so that f is now one-to-one. Furthermore, I require that if $x_i$ is the $i^{th}$ entry. Choose $x_i=k$ for some $k$, then it must be separated from all other images with $x_i\neq k$ by at least $10^{-i}$. Does this give me the natural ordering?